# Firefox not waiting for user interaction with data-confirm alert on delete method in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, firefox

When a user presses the delete button an alert pops up with 'Are you sure [ok][cancel]?'. Instead of waiting for user input the delete method is run and the page redirects to the next step.  I have included a jquery submit function that is saving the current state of another form on the page before moving to the delete action. I can't seem to find any info on html5 data-confirm attribute compatibility issues in firefox 10.  The functionality is perfect in chrome and ie. Any ideas on how to fix this?  Seems like I am missing something simple here.

```
View



    <td style="padding:2px;padding-left:6px;"><%= link_to 'Delete', 
                store_store_hour_path(@store,store_hour),  :class=>"button small white saveForm",
                :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>




Controller
<pre><code>
SAVE = "Save"
CANCEL = "Cancel"


class StoreHoursController < SecuredController
  before_filter :grab_store_from_store_id

  # GET /store_hours/new
  # GET /store_hours/new.xml
  def new
    @store_hour = @store.store_hours.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @store_hour }
    end
  end

  # POST /store_hours
  # POST /store_hours.xml
  def create
    @store_hour = @store.store_hours.new(params[:store_hour])
    @store = @store_hour.store
    if params[:commit] == CANCEL
      redirect_to edit_store_path(@store)
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @store_hour.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_store_path(@store), :flash => { :success => 'Store hours created successfully' } }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @store_hour, :status => :created, :location => @store_hour }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new", :flash => { :success => 'Store hours created successfully' }  }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @store_hour.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /store_hours/1/edit
  def edit
    @store_hour = @store.store_hours.find(params[:id])
  end

  # PUT /store_hours/1
  # PUT /store_hours/1.xml
  def update
    @store_hour = @store.store_hours.find(params[:id])
    @store = @store_hour.store
    if params[:commit] == CANCEL
      redirect_to edit_store_path(@store)
      return
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @store_hour.update_attributes(params[:store_hour])
        format.html { redirect_to edit_store_path(@store), :flash => { :success => 'Store hours updated successfully' } }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @store_hour.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /store_hours/1
  # DELETE /store_hours/1.xml
  def destroy
    @store_hour = @store.store_hours.find(params[:id])
    @store = @store_hour.store
    @store_hour.destroy

    logger.info "in destroy: " + edit_store_path(@store)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to edit_store_path(@store), :flash => { :success => 'Store hours deleted successfully' } }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private

  def grab_store_from_store_id
      @store=Store.find(params[:store_id])
  end

 end

Jquery submit

function saveStoreInfo() {
$('.saveForm').click(function(){ $('#storeForm').submit(); return true});

}
```

Comment: :onclick => "confirm('Are you sure?'); return true;"

The above code works just fine, seems that FF10 has an issue with the HTML5 attribute data-confirm but I cannot find any documentation on it.  Will be sending an email to Mozilla soon

Comment: This is also happening to me on FF8 (Mac OS X). Works fine on Chrome 18 (mac)